# Equivalence of the Sup/Inf Definition of the Integral

Tags: calculus

If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable prove that 
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \sup\left\{ \int_a^b g(x) dx : g \text{ is continuous and } g \leq  f \right\} $$ $$ =  \inf\left\{ \int_a^b h(x) dx : h \text{ is continuous and } f \leq h \right\}.$$

Something just doesn't add up when I try to prove this. Please help.

Sorry if this is written badly. This is my first post.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? Also, which definition of the definite integral do you use?

Comment: I can't see why it's true Intuitively so it's hard for me to form a proof.
It's the defintion by Riemann.  I'll be happy for an Intuitive explanation, once I'll understand why it's true, it will be easier to write the proof.

Comment: We need more than that for the "definition by Riemann" since there are several. The details matter for this kind of proof. Do you mean the first definition given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Definition) or another one?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the definition of integral on an interval that I use in this answer. The integral of a piecewise-constant function over an interval is very easy to find: just integrate each constant piece and add the integrals. Given real values $a$ and $b$ and a bounded function $f(x)$ defined on $[a,b]$, we define

$$S_L=\sup\left\{ \int_a^b p(x)\,dx \mid p(x)\text{ is piecewise-constant and $p(x)\le f(x)$ for $a\le x\le b$ } \right\}$$
$$S_U=\inf\left\{ \int_a^b q(x)\,dx \mid q(x)\text{ is piecewise-constant and $q(x)\ge f(x)$ for $a\le x\le b$ } \right\}$$

Then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is defined if and only if $S_L=S_U$, and it equals that common value.

Here is a graph of an integrable but non-continuous function $f(x)$, shown in solid black. A piecewise-constant function $p(x)\le f(x)$ is shown in solid blue and piecewise-constant function $q(x)\ge f(x)$ is shown in solid red.

[image]

We can make a continuous function $g(x)$, shown in dashed cyan, that closely approximates $p(x)$ and is below it: $g(x)$ equals $p(x)$ except for a small area near endpoints. We can
make the integral of $g(x)$ as close as we like to the integral of $p(x)$.

The supremum of the integrals of the continuous $g(x)$'s equals the integral of $p(x)$, and the supremum of the integrals of the $p(x)$'s equals the integral of $f(x)$. Therefore, the supremum of the integrals of the continuous $g(x)$'s equals the integral of $f(x)$, as we wanted.

We can do the same with $h(x)$'s, shown in dashed orange, above $q(x)$ to get the other part of your problem. I left out a few steps, but this should give you the intuition and overview of the proof that you want.